# How can I get all alpabetic letters in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I get all alphabetic letters?

I need to get all alphabetic letters in an array like: `array('a','b','c'...);`

Comment: In what context? And which alphabet?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write the array once and be done with it?  Could also `$arr=explode(" ","a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z");`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function like this:

```
$letters = range('a', 'z');
print_r($letters);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => f
    [6] => g
    [7] => h
    [8] => i
    [9] => j
    [10] => k
    [11] => l
    [12] => m
    [13] => n
    [14] => o
    [15] => p
    [16] => q
    [17] => r
    [18] => s
    [19] => t
    [20] => u
    [21] => v
    [22] => w
    [23] => x
    [24] => y
    [25] => z
)
```

Comment: And if you want to get it as a string, just use the implode function: `implode('', range('a', 'd')` => `abcd`.

Answer (score 8):

Use range to do this, which makes it easy.

```
$az = range('a', 'z');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i=65; $i<=90; ++$i) print chr($i)
```

65 is the ascii code for A

Answer (score 2):

```
$lower = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');

$upper = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G','H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');
```

For problems that have finite solutions, sometimes the best thing you can do is just hard code each one.

Answer (score 2):

```
$alphas = range('A', 'Z');
foreach($alphas as $value){
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

Print A-Z Result

try this....

Output is:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with my example.

```
<?php

$letters =  '=======Alphabets========' . PHP_EOL;
echo  $letters;

$alphabets = "A";

for ($i=0; $i < strlen($letters); $i++) { 
   echo "<br>".$alphabets++ . PHP_EOL;
}
```